# Change layout for Devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using gem `devise`. Devise extends application controller and adds user managment to rails application.

When I look inside the gem I can see following line

```
class Devise::SessionsController < ApplicationController
```

I am trying to change this since I want Devise controller to inherit from my custom controller named `AdminController`. Reason for this is I have whole web application finished and I do not want admin part of the page to use my application layout, css, js ...

How can I dynamically change base class of controller? Or dynamically tell controller to use `admin.html.erb` layout instead of `application.html.erb` layout.

When I say "dynamicly" I mean monkey patch it, thank you.

Comment: You can specify layout in controller http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html I am looking for a way to monkey patch `Devise::SessionsController` with custom layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem, if namespace of controller is `Devise` use admin layout.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  layout :determine_layout

  def determine_layout
    module_name = self.class.to_s.split("::").first
    return (module_name.eql?("Devise") ? "admin" : "application")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey. That's really cool! We live and we learn, and that's what makes it fun, hope the day when I know it all _never_ comes ; )

Answer (score 2):

Devise is a [rails engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). I think that the best way to make a admin section of you site is to make a rails engine. Or better still use [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) or [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info/). They are both rails engines There is a railscast about [rails engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines)

I don't know the inner works of you app, but if you add

```
layout "admin"
```

to your AdminController and add a custom admin layout to the view/layouts folder with

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "admin"%>
```

the AdminController views will use the admin stylesheet and javascript

Comment: These gems are very nice thank you, still I am just calling that part of site "admin" real reason I need devise is user management. I do not think that devise has it's own application controller since it uses my application controller. I want devise page to use layout different from one defined in application layout.

Comment: Perhaps [CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) could help you out. Updating my answer

Comment: Sorry, devise does not have it's own application controller

Comment: Thanks for help Andreas, I figured it out. If you want to specify special logic to assigning layouts see above. We live and learn, hope day comes when I know it all :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to change the layout, I think you should be able to do it by re-opening the controller class. At the bottom of your `initializers/devise.rb` (underneath the config section at the top level, you could write:

```
Devise::SessionsController.layout :admin
```

I've not tried this, but in theory it should work since layout is just a class method on ActionController.base.

Comment: Tried it, it said there is not 'layout=' method.

Comment: @Dolphin You've put an '=' sign in where one shouldn't be. You should be able to do the above (i.e. `layout :admin`, *not* `layout = :admin`).

Comment: Wow this worked. `Devise::RegistrationsController.layout false` at end of `devise.rb` and restart the server. Not the result I expected, but it worked.